# How to use GPU computing with radial basis networks in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

The ways I know to create radial basis networks in Neural Network Toolbox is newrb and newrbe but as far as I searched these functions do not enable to use GPU acceleration. How can I use GPU computation with such network type.

Btw. my original problem is how to increase whole program performance. It is program testing this network in certain problem which results in many nested loops iterating various simulation parameters. In that way I get a lot of train and sim processes. I currently use matlabpool and parfor but execution time is still ultimately long (many hours).

Comment: I am also researching this option; I have found [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/nnet/nnet_ug.pdf) I know it is not that helpfull; TLDR: its not possible to use GPU acceleration and use `newrb()`.